# Return a single row when multiple rows exist for a specific reference

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

My SQL skills have gone rusty from non-use and would like to ask for some assistance to the following.

I have a Product table, a Customer table and an Order Reference table. A customer can order 1 or multiple products within the same Order Reference.

The SQL query I have written is:

```
SELECT O.ORDER_REF, P.Product, C.Name
FROM PRODUCTS AS P
INNER JOIN ORDER_REFS AS O ON P.ORDER_REF = O.ORDER_REF
INNER JOIN CUST AS C ON P.ORDER_REF = C.ORDER_REF
WHERE P.PROD_CODE =`A`
AND P.ORDER_DATE = '2019-11-01'
ORDER BY O.APP_REF ASC;
```

I only want the customers that bought Product 'A' **only**.
The result from my query above delivers all those that ordered 'A', but also A&B and A&C etc.

Table O, is like this where there are mutiple rows per ORDER_REF:

```
ORDER_REF PRODUCT NAME
1     |     A     | Mr X
1     |     B     | Mr X
2     |     A     | Mr Y
3     |     A     | Mr T
4     |     A     | Mr S
5     |     A     | Mr W
5     |     C     | Mr W
```

The result I want would show the below as they only bought 'A'

```
 ORDER_REF  PRODUCT     NAME 
    2     |     A     | Mr Y
    3     |     A     | Mr T
    4     |     A     | Mr S
```

I've tried SELECT DISTINCT but to no avail so any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

> I only want the customers that bought Product 'A' only.

Use aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT C.Name
FROM PRODUCTS P INNER JOIN
     ORDER_REFS O
     ON P.ORDER_REF = O.ORDER_REF INNER JOIN
     CUST C
     ON P.ORDER_REF = C.ORDER_REF
WHERE P.ORDER_DATE = '2019-11-01'
GROUP BY C.NAME
HAVING MIN(P.PROD_CODE) = 'A' AND MAX(P.PROD_CODE) = 'A';
```

Your sample results have additional columns.  However, those do not seem relevant to your question.